# Normal for CLSID stays the same but IID changes for new version of OCX?

Tags: .net, com, vb6, com-interop, ocx

I am developing a C# .NET application that uses an externally developed (I believe in VB6) ActiveX controller, which I import from a OCX-file using Aximp.exe. Each time I get a new version of the OCX I have to re-run Aximp.exe or else there is a `InvalidCastException` With message:

> This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM
>   component for the interface with IID
>   '{X13535F4-2X96-4F87-80E6-X342AD8X3E7F}' failed due to the following
>   error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
>   (E_NOINTERFACE))

When comparing the TypeLib output from Oleview.exe for different version of the OCX the only thing that changes are the IID:s and version number. The CLSID stays the same.

Is it normal that the IID:s changes but CLSID:s stay the same between versions?

Would this IID:s indicate that the OCX is not being built with "Binary compatibility" enabled (if it really is made with VB6)?

Is there anything I should be doing to maintain compatibility with new versions of the OCX without re-running Axim.exe rebuilding the application?

Comment: I believe that this is the behavior when the VB6 version compatibility settings are 'project compatibility'.  If it were 'no compatibility', then the clsid would also be changed on every compile. You'll need to have your external developer use binary compatibility or you need to re-import (re-read) the new interface definitions on each release. It could be that if the interface is being changed on new releases (changing the existing methods, properties, events), then binary compatibility is not possible - new methods, properties and events can be added and binary compatibility is maintained.

Comment: @MarkL - you should post an answer. "binary compatibility" was the way to keep GUIDs stable. Note VB does not that by default because since the interface changes (method layout, method signature), the interface is supposed to be a brand new interface. If you choose "binary compatibility" you may experience crashes it the interface does change significantly... it's a design/engineering choice

Comment: @SimonMourier - I considered posting this as an answer, but held off and made it a comment as it seemed that the OP wasn't sure what was happening with their external developer(s). You're correct as to binary compatibility, and vb6 will display a warning when you go to recompile and you have binary compatibility set but you've made changes to the interface(s) (at least changes from the referenced compatible target). Depending on how one reacts to and makes selections on that confusing warning screen, the consuming clients may or may not work, understanding COM compatibility is a must for that.